# Angular2 Injection - difference between using private vs @Inject

Tags: dependency-injection, angular

Could someone explain what is difference between,

```
constructor(@Inject(Config) config:Config) {
     this.config = config;
}
```

and,

```
constructor(private config:Config) {

}
```

Assuming that Config is supplied from bootstrap function in Angular2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @Inject decorator allows you to specify hints about what to inject. In your case, you don't need it because you use a type for your parameter. It's a decorator provided by Angular2.

From the Angular2 documentation ( https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/InjectMetadata-class.html):

> When @Inject isn't present, the injector will use the type annotation of the parameter.

The @Inject decorator can be use with forwardRef since ES6 / TypeScript classes don't support hoisting or with à string if you want inject Ng1 services / factories.

The private keyword allows you to define the parameter as private property of the class. It's a feature of the TypeScript language.

Comment: *"you don't need it because you use a type for your parameter"* - it depends on in what class OP is trying to inject `config`. He might or might not need `Inject`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment, @dfsq! I agree with you if you want to use for example forwardRef... I'll update a bit my answer ;-)